# Custom UITable not populating in simulator with Json File

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, tableview, datasource

My question is why doesn't my UITableView populate in the simulator? I am creating a UITableView programmatically and I am having a very hard time getting the table to show itself, let alone display my data from the JSON File. I use SwiftUi, but I decided to create something different. I have no errors in my app, the only thing I can think of is something with the JSON File and how it's parsed. I uploaded a smaller version of my JSON file so that someone could please verify this issue. Thank you.

```
struct UserData: Codable {
let albums: [Album]
let playlists: [Playlist]
}

struct Album: Codable {
  let title, id: String
  let imageURL: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case title, id
    case imageURL = "imageUrl"
  }
}


struct Playlist: Codable {
  let title: String
  let albums: [String]
  let id: String
}



class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var albums = [Album]()
  var playlists = [Playlist]()

  let tableView : UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return table
  }()


  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return albums.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let text = albums[indexPath.row].title
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
  }
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    parseJson()
  }

  private func parseJson(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data (1)", ofType: "json") else {
        return
    }
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
      let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
      let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: jsonData)
      albums = userData.albums
      playlists = userData.playlists
      tableView.reloadData()
    } catch{
        print("error : \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON Sample**

```
 {
   "albums":[
  {
     "title":"The Impossible Kid",
     "id":"0",
     "imageUrl":"https://showmusic-stack-showmusicimagese9e4bdae-lfk59pk2d0j2.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/albums/0.jpg"
  },
  {
     "id":"1",
     "title":"Funeral",
     "imageUrl":"https://showmusic-stack-showmusicimagese9e4bdae-lfk59pk2d0j2.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/albums/1.jpg"
  },

  ],
 "playlists":[
  {
     "title":"Favorites",
     "albums":[
        "1",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "2"
     ],
     "id":"0"
  },
  {
     "title":"To Check Out",
     "albums":[
        "3",
        "14",
        "18",
        "0",
        "29"
     ],
     "id":"1"
  }
```

Comment: Do you realise that your table view has 0 width and 0 height because you passed in `.zero` for the frame? Did you add any constraints to it that you omitted in the code that you posted?

Comment: No, I didn't, thanks for point that out to me. I was pulling things together here just trying to understand. and no, I didn't add any constraints. Will that be a function for subviewLayoutsWillAppear? @Sweeper

Comment: Why are you loading data under `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here:

```
let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
```

You created a table view with a frame of `.zero`, so it has 0 width and 0 height, which is why you can't see it.

You can add constraints to the table view so that it is positioned correctly in `self.view`. For example, if you want it to use all the available space in `self.view`, aligning its 4 edges with the 4 edges of `self.view`, you can do this:

```
// do this after self.view.addSubview(table)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    table.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
])
```

Comment: Or `table.frame = view.bounds` for short.

Comment: Yeah, but you should not do that in `viewDidLoad`. I just wanted to introduce OP to auto layout, because it is more expressive and flexible. @ChuckZHB

Comment: Agreed. That's just an option for a simple viewcontroller, because it saves code. Would I know where should I put it in, if not `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: If you put it in `viewDidLoad`, then when the user rotates the screen, the table view frame will not change to fit the new screen orientation and will appear very weird. I would do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. @ChuckZHB

Comment: Yes, the tableView will still fit the new screen orientation when using Anchors if set in `viewDidLoad`. I miss that point.